# Python code to replace specific list of strings

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, replace, slice

Hey I'm currently using python to read a list of string in a txt file and I wanted to cut off multiple strings in the front e.g

example in my txt file:

```
Jack: Black

Jack: Sparrow

Jimm: Oliver

Jimm: Next

Jimm: Red

Ston: Cold

Bill: Black
```

I wanted to remove the first 5 string (including ':') from each line so the desired result might be

```
Black

Sparrow

Oliver

Next

Red

Cold

Black
```

I've been trying using .replace() but I cannot determine the string neither using string slicing (it will cut only the few characters in the first line)

currently my program looks like this:

```
with open("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Zha\\Desktop\\test3.txt", "r") as text:
    a = text.read()
    b = str(a).replace(a[:5],'')
    print b
```

and the current output is

```
 Black

 Sparrow

Jimm: Oliver

Jimm: Next

Jimm: Red

Ston: Cold

Bill: Black
```

Comment: Might I also add: `awk test3.txt '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over each line in the file:

```
with open(filename, "r") as text:
    for line in text:
        print line[6:]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `split`:

```
with open("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Zha\\Desktop\\test3.txt", "r") as text:
    for line in text:
        if line.strip():
            print line.split(':')[1].strip()
```

Answer (score 1):

`a` is the whole of the file, as a string:

```
"Jack: Black\nJack: Sparrow\nJimm: Oliver\n" # and so on
```

so `a[:5] == 'Jack:'`, which you duly replace all occurrences of, but this doesn't do anything with the lines that don't include those characters.

For what you are trying to achieve, `readlines()` (which gives a list where each item is one line as a string) in combination with `split` is probably more use:

```
b = [line.split()[1] for line in text.readlines()]
```

i.e. "for each line in the file, split on whitespace and give me the second part". This gives `b == ["Black", "Sparrow", "Oliver", ...]` and means you aren't limited to lines where the first part is exactly 5 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the following code:

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
  f = f.readlines()

f = [i[6:].strip() for i in f]

print f

[OUTPUT]
['Black', 'Sparrow', 'Oliver', 'Next', 'Red', 'Cold', 'Black']
```